# Python Typing: how to get Type[C] to work with TypeVars and Generics?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting

I am trying to figure out how to get Python generic type-hinting to play nice with a constructor argument of Type[C]. Consider this code sample:

```
class Foo(object):
  fooval: str

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.fooval = val

class Bar(object):
  barval: str

  def __init__(self, val):
    self.barval = val

T = TypeVar('T', Foo, Bar)

class FooBarContainer(Generic[T]):
  child: T

  # Type[T] seems logical here, but that's not valid according to the docs
  def __init__(self, ctorable: Type[Union[Foo, Bar]], val):
    self.child = ctorable(val)

baz = FooBarContainer(Foo, val)
# This does not get flagged by type-checkers, but will obviously fail at runtime
failure = baz.child.barval
```

Attempting to use Type[T] results in a type-checker error:

> Expected Type[T], got Type[Foo]

So the goal here is to figure out how to get TypeVars to work with the Type[C] from typing. This way static analysis would know that when I call a particular func with a particular Type[T], I am expecting to get T back. I can't seem to find any docs that would help me here.

The same issue arises when dealing with functions too. For example, this is valid syntax, but obviously not valid in terms of typing:

```
def initor(thing_type: Type[Union[Foo, Bar]], val) -> T:
  return thing_type(val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "Type[T] seems logical here, but that's not valid according to the docs"?

In particular, what docs are you looking at? The following code works as expected for me, using mypy 0.630:

```
class FooBarContainer(Generic[T]):
  child: T

  def __init__(self, ctorable: Type[T], val) -> None:
    self.child = ctorable(val)

val = 3
baz = FooBarContainer(Foo, val)

# Mypy reports a `"Foo" has no attribute "barval"` error
failure = baz.child.barval
```

If the docs imply giving `ctorable` a type of `Type[T]` does not work, they should probably be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using PyCharm's type inspection to analyze this, so now I am wondering if that's my issue then! I'll have to test mypy against my code and see how it does instead. This gives me a good lead.  

The docs I am looking at are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type
I may be misreading this line: The only legal parameters for Type are classes, unions of classes, and Any. I wasn't sure if TypeVar is a valid value here, and the fact that PyCharm didn't seem capable of understanding Type[T] gave me a potentially false bias.

Comment: @Zoinks -- oh, that's embarrassing... I was actually the person who contributed that particular section of the docs -- I'm not really sure why I wrote that. It's possible that `Type[T]` was indeed not considered 2 years ago (which is when I wrote that section of the docs); it's also possible I just forgot about typevars entirely. And somewhat irritatingly, [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) gives a completely different answer: it seems to think `Type[T]` is legal, but only when annotating the first argument of a class method...

Comment: In any case, I'll ask around + post an update comment once I get clarification.

Comment: Oh, very neat! I appreciate your time on this, thank you.

Comment: @Zoinks -- fyi the typing docs are [updated now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type); PEP 484 might take a little longer to update mostly because the necessary wording changes require a little more work.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the update. I am sticking to using Type[T] for now as mypy is happy with it and it's the expected usage as you point out.
I'll have to wait for PyCharm to catch up. I've filed a bug with PyCharm for the static analyzer issue where it does not play well with TypeVar constraints. I was able to prove that the Type[T]->T construct works for TypeVars without constraints.